# react component state change after ajax call but does not rerender component

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

On this part the user gets to comment on posts. After it gets checked on server side and the data is recieved, I try to change the `this.state.comments` value. and so it's done. But the problem is, it is not changing the comment section on component.
I have read the previous questions about rerendering so please don't mark as duplicate. Below is the code:

```
$.post("requests.php", {
    requestKey: 'newComment',
    commenterUser: commenterUser,
    commenterEmail: commenterEmail,
    theComment: theComment,
    pnum: pnum}, function(data, status, xhr){
      if(status == 'success'){
        if(data == 'commented'){
          this.setState({
            comments: data
          })
        }else{

        }
      }
    });
```

The `data` received is all the comments related to the post and the comments section is a place where all the comments are shown.

Comment: `this.setState` should not work here because `this` would be undefined, you should use arrow function or save this value before the post -> `var that = this;`, then user `that.setState` in the callback

Comment: @Deepak but I've already written `onSubmit={this.submitComment.bind(this)}` and the value of `state.commens` do change. :(

Comment: this is function scoped, even if you have bound your current function with this, you have another function inside submitComment. Either change the inner function to be an arrow function or the solution of @OlivierBoissé will do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use arrow function instead of doing manual binding.

this.setState is not working because it has scope issue when you use normal function.

Change it to arrow function. Check below code

```
   $.post("requests.php", {
        requestKey: 'newComment',
        commenterUser: commenterUser,
        commenterEmail: commenterEmail,
        theComment: theComment,
            pnum: pnum}, (data, status, xhr) => {
                if(status == 'success'){
                    if(data == 'commented'){
                        this.setState({
                            comments: data
                        })
                    }else{

              }
           }
       });
```

Edit:

If you want to stay away with scope issues you can use arrow function. When you use arrow function then you no need to bind your function manually in constructor

```
 submitComment = () => {

 }
```

If you use normal function and to play with state or props inside that function, then you need to manually refer current object to a local variable like below

```
 let that = this;
 that.setState({
     name: “update”
 });
```

Sorry if there are any typo mistakes. I am answering in mobile

Comment: thanks, but what if I used `onSubmit={this.submitComment.bind(this)}`?

Comment: Updated my post for your question. Check answer

Comment: thanks, it's working well now. appreciate your time:)

Answer (score 2):

```
let _this = this;
$.post("requests.php", {
  requestKey: 'newComment',
  commenterUser: commenterUser,
  commenterEmail: commenterEmail,
  theComment: theComment,
  pnum: pnum
}, function(data, status, xhr){
    if  (status == 'success'){
       if(data == 'commented'){
          _this.setState({ comments: data })
       } else{

       }
    }
});
```

I think the issue is with your scope of `this`, in javascript `this` is always in lexical context.

Comment: thanks, but what if I used `onSubmit={this.submitComment.bind(this)}`?

Comment: It's the callback that would need to be binded.

Answer (score 2):

You have a scope problem.

Let's consider this example:

```
function foo() {
    this.bar = 'lorem';
    this.ipsum = function() {
        console.log(this.bar);
    };
}
```

If you call `ipsum`, it will log `undefined`, because the `this` there refers to the `ipsum` `function`. Let's consider this example:

```
function foo() {
    this.bar = 'lorem';
    var that = this;
    this.ipsum = function() {
        console.log(that.bar);
    };
}
```

In this case `that` stores the outer `this`, so `'lorem'` will be logged if `ipsum` is called. Let's consider an example for an arrow function:

```
function foo() {
    this.bar = 'lorem';
    this.ipsum = () => {
        console.log(this.bar);
    };
}
```

In this case if you call `ipsum` `'lorem'` will be written to the console.

You can also use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for this purpose.

Let's use an arrow function for your example:

```
$.post("requests.php", {
    requestKey: 'newComment',
    commenterUser: commenterUser,
    commenterEmail: commenterEmail,
    theComment: theComment,
    pnum: pnum}, (data, status, xhr) => {
      if(status == 'success'){
        if(data == 'commented'){
          this.setState({
            comments: data
          })
        }else{

        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: well, thank you. the text was so comprehensive. appreciate your time:)